# Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, android-studio

С чем может быть связана следующая ошибка и как ее исправить?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
    is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете версии `25.3.1` , а он хочет, чтобы было `26.0.0-alpha1`.

Не забудьте изменить значения `compileSdkVersion` и `targetSdkVersion` на 26.

---

**Например:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

---

*P.S. А вообще, на данный момент доступна версия [27.0.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-1).*

*`compileSdkVersion` и `targetSdkVersion` на 27.*